# Why do I need to run PluginInstall every time to use Black inside vim?

Tags: vim, vundle

I just installed Black from:

```
Plugin 'ambv/black', {'rtp': 'vim'}
```

using Vundle.

I am not able to use the `Black` command without running `PluginInstall`.

Is this a bug?

The plugin is [here](https://github.com/ambv/black/blob/master/plugin/black.vim)

My .vimrc looks like this:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ambv/black', {'rtp': 'vim'}
call vundle#end()
```

Comment: is the line you posted inside of 
```call vundle#begin()``` and ```call vundle#end()```

Comment: @TylerFowle I have added the contents of my .vimrc

Comment: did you get the "Please wait, one time setup for Black" message after doing `:PluginInstall` in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after reading the [Vundle documentation](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) it seems you are missing some required lines in your `.vimrc`

but I think the main issue is that you are changing the rtp of black, removing that works with the following `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible             "required
filetype off                 "required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ambv/black'
call vundle#end()            " required

filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who ran into this problem (including with other plugins), check your spelling. If the github username/repository pair contains a typo, then github will ask for a password.

Comment: happened to me with a different repos